# Sublime Text 3 sidebar files and folders freeze or not showing

Tags: macos, sublimetext, sublimetext3, osx-yosemite

Sometimes when I open my sublime text, I have this problem:

[image: sublime text sidebar freezes]

And then I need to restart sublime 2 or 3 times for back to work correctly.

How can I solve that? Or it's a bug?

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?  I'm considering switching to Atom because of this issue.

Comment: I not find any solution my friend. Now I'm using Ubuntu for work, and this is not happens anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem several times with Sublime on Windows. Removing the Sublime folder in app data fixes it, although you will lose certain remembered settings - better to have the folders back in the editor though!

Here's where to find appdata:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2690709/whats-in-the-hidden-windows-appdata-folder-and-how-to-find-it-if-you-need-it.html

Remember to only removed Sublime data!